# How to remove days or other elements from this countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm in a need of something super basic, and inline. I found this on here, but I've been trying to ticker with it and get the days removed. Every time I do it's blinking differently or repeating the clock over and over again. Any suggestions would be greatly appericated.

```js
var end = new Date('11/30/2016 12:00 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: seriously? just put a condition where you appending the days/hours to the innerHTML such that if any of these is 0 no need to append

Comment: Put your days line inside an if which checks to see if days is positive

Comment: @Manish wanna mark up an example? I new to javascript, never used it in my LIFE.

Comment: @adambwhitten check the answer i posted. Feel free to ask if you need any clarifications.

Comment: @Manish you are awesome man. I guess I just need to dive into JavaScript to really understand it more.

Comment: @adambwhitten JavaScript is very easy to learn if you have experience with other programming language it will be even easier. All the best and Happy learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@adambwhitten Please have a look at the example below. Have shown how to handle days when 0. Similarly you can handle other parts of the Timer. In the else condition have set the iinnerHTML to empty string as you need to clear the contents first and then append the rest of the timer values. If you dont't do that it will keep on appending the text to it. Hope it helps

```js
var end = new Date('12/1/2016 12:00 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
        if(days!=0){
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
        }else{
          //clear the existing text
          
          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '';
        }

      //similary can handle other parts be hours/minutes
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally just remove the days from the string build...

```js
var end = new Date('11/30/2016 12:00 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Thats weird. I did that and it kept adding the countdown over and over. But this works now. I'm loosing my mind? Sheesh. Thanks!!!

Comment: You didn't remove the `+` before the first string assignment, which meant it was always adding to the existing string.  Notice it's `=` on the first line and `+=` on subsequent lines.